# Stuck with an overloading operator program

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm having an issue where my program just crashes and I'm not sure what the cause is. I've tried to trim down the above to only the pertinent information. So basically what I want to happen is when in main I use the code in main.cpp, I want it to reference the code I gave in the deck.cpp section. It should print out the entire deck, but all that happens is my program crashes before printing anything. Are there any blaring issues I need to fix? Any help would be very much appreciated.

deck.h

```
class Deck
{
private:

    // Private Data Members
    struct card{
        string face; // A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K
        string suit; // H,C,D,S
        int sn;      // Serial Number
        card* next;
    };

    card *top;       // Top of the deck
    int size;        // Size of the deck
    int numDecks;    // Number of traditional decks in this deck of cards   

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ,const Deck& );
    string operator[](int );
    Deck operator--();       // Prefix decrement operator.  
    Deck operator--(int);
    Deck operator++();       // Prefix decrement operator.  
    Deck operator++(int);
```

deck.cpp

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Deck& crd)
{
    Deck::card *ptr; // parsing pointer
    ptr = crd.top;
    output << "Total number of cards: " << crd.size << endl;    // Displays the number of cards in the deck
    int z = 1;
    while(ptr !=NULL)
    {
        output << z << ".  " << ptr->face << "-" << ptr->suit;                                      // Outputs the number in the deck, face, and suit of a card
        if(z%4 == 0)                                            // Creative output formatting
            output<< endl;
        else if(z < 10)                                         // More creative output formatting
            output <<"\t\t";
        else                                                    // Even more creative output formatting
            output << "\t";
        ptr = ptr->next;                                        // Move the parsing pointer to the next card
        z++;                                                    // Increment the number
    }
    output << endl << endl;
    return output;
}
```

main.cpp

```
 int main()
{

    Deck deck; // Creates a Deck Object

    deck.shuffle(1); // Shuffles one traditional deck of cards into the Deck Object

    deck.displayDeck(); // Displays the Deck of cards

    cout << "Card 1: "<<deck.getCard() << endl; // Removes top deck of the card and displays it to the screen
    cout << "Card 2: "<<deck.getCard() << endl; // Removes top deck of the card and displays it to the screen
    cout << "Card 3: "<<deck.getCard() << endl; // Removes top deck of the card and displays it to the screen

    cout << endl<<endl;

    cout << "Remove 2 Cards."<<endl;
    --deck; //  Removes a Card - Prefix
    deck--; //  Removes a Card - Postfix
    cout << endl<<endl; 

    // Alternate way of displaying the deck of cards
    cout << "Total number of cards: " << deck.getSize() << endl;
    for(int i = 1; i <=deck.getSize(); i++) // getSize() returns the number of cards in the deck
    {   
        cout <<i<<setw(4)<<left<< setfill(' ')<<".";
        cout <<setw(5)<<setfill(' ')<<left << deck[i-1]<< "\t";
        if(i%4 == 0) // Formatting to make the display a little easier to read
            cout<< endl;
    }
    cout << endl<<endl<<endl;

    cout << "Add 2 Cards."<<endl;
    ++deck; //  Adds a card back to the deck - Prefix
    deck++; //  Adds a card back to the deck - Postfix 
    cout <<endl<<endl;

    cout << deck;   // Displays the Deck of cards

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it already crashes before printing "Total number of cards [...]" then the only reason I can see is that `crd` is a  dangling reference in the call of `operator<<`. Can you please add all the parts of `main.cpp` that deal with the variable `deck`?

Comment: I edited the original post to show the rest of main.cpp

Comment: And you really no not even get the "Total number of cards" output? Do you get a stack trace? If not, then it is probably best to step through it with a debugger to find the exact place where it crashes.

Comment: No it doesnt even print that, I use cmd line with GCC for compiling so I don't have a debugger

Comment: Even when you compile on the comand line the debugger `gdb` should still be available. But it might suffice to compile with the additional `-fsanitize=address` flag and run it again.

Comment: Looks like your problem will be caused inside shuffle() or displayDeck(). Catch some exceptions and display the error messages.